# Why this recursion prints multiple lines?

Tags: python, recursion

Can someone please explain me how this Python recursion code works?
I just cannot understand why it prints six numbers and not just one (21)... and why does it start with 1?
Sorry I'm very noob, I know... Your kind help would be very much appreciated.

**Code:**

```
def func(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + func(k - 1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Results")
func(6)
```

**Output:**

```
Recursion Results
1
3
6
10
15
21
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `print(result)` inside `func(k)`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `print(result)` executes after each (recursive) call to `func` returns.

Comment: `func(6)` calls `func(5)`, which calls `func(4)`, etc.

Comment: If you only want the final value, put the `print` call inside the `else` block instead iof `if`.

Comment: Python tutor is a great resource for understanding why your code is doing something like this. Try this URL:  https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20func%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%20%3E%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20k%20%2B%20func%28k%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result%0A%0Aprint%28%22%5Cn%5CnRecursion%20Results%22%29%0Afunc%286%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: @chepner  OK... that seems to be clear... but the variable "result" should be already more than 6 in the 3rd line of the "func" function, shouldn't it? (since k=6) Why does it start to print numbers from 1?

Comment: Each time you call `func`, it makes a recursive call *before* executing `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, every time `func(k)` gets called with `k > 0`, the `print` statement will be invoked.  `func` is being called repeatedly or recursively so `print` is repeatedly called so you are seeing multiple lines.

Remove the `print` from your `func` and do `print(func(6))` to display just the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Well basically when your code runs the 3rd line (result = k + func(k - 1)), it first looks at fun(k-1) (which is 5 if you start with 6), so it runs that until you get to  (result = k + func(k - 1)) again, in which it prioritizes fun(k-1) again... until your fun(k-1) == fun(0).

At fun(0) the code runs your else statement (so it printes nothing) and it will go back to the fun(1), in which it will print 1 before returning the value... until you get to fun(6).

If you want to see what your code does step by step, i would recommend you to use python tutor, which is a site that lets you see step by step what is happening in your code.

Have fun learning python!!!

(ps, here is the link for the site: https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)